# Can't end a while loop using .hasNextInt()

Tags: java

I am writing a program in which a user inputs an unknown amount of numbers on a single line, like: `2 6 3 9 12`.

I have to insert those numbers in a queue. However the loop doesn't end until I enter a non-integer value. I found one solution online which was to use `.useDelimiter(" *")`. This works except for when I enter a two digit integer: it splits it into two separate numbers. Is there a way to end this loop without having to enter a non integer value?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)
while(in.hasNextInt())
{
    myQueue.insert(in.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Does "return" count as a "non-integer value" to end the loop?

Comment: It is certainly possible - you need to decide the exit criteria and add it to the while loop i.e. while(in.hasNextInt() !! <other criteria>) {...}. One way to do it is maybe check for in.hasNextLine() and break.

Comment: Are the numbers always entered on one line?

Comment: no return doesn't count David and yeah the numbers are always on one line Elliot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the numbers are on one line, you could read the line and construct a `Scanner` on that text. Something like,

```
System.out.println("Please enter a line of integer values: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
if (in.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = in.nextLine();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        myQueue.insert(scan.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pshemo if the `if` check wasn't there and the application was run with stdin redirected from /dev/null, it would throw a NoSuchElement exception. The `if` guards against that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(in.hasNextLine())
{
    try {
      myQueue.insert(Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please no, never ever use try-catch as decision mechanism with Scanner. We have `Scanner#hasNextInt` method for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. There are a number of ways to do this. You could modify your current code by adding the line:

```
in.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

This will delimit the iterator to a new line correctly on any platform.